# Is possible to use Native Android submodule and iOS cocoapods into a flutter plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, cocoapods, git-submodules

I've made a map functionality using Google Maps SDK, for Android and iOS as Android Submodule and Cocoapods components respectively. I already integrate both into a Flutter project and it works fine.

But I want to create a flutter plugin that use these components for further use (without copy native code into this plugin). It's possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Comment: Hi man, thanks. I've read this article, but it doesn't explain how to put git submodule code into a flutter plugin. That's my problem.
When I put the git submodule code into an flutter app, I need to write this line     implementation project(':projectname') into app build.gradle file. But on plugin I doesn't have this file, then I don't know where I need to put it.

Comment: I think it's not possible, I need to create AAR files from my modules to use it on my flutter plugin.

Comment: Hii, Any luck on this @XandeRastaMoura ? 
I would like to do exactly the same.... but I will probably go with a generated Jar of my android native library for now.

Comment: Hi @Tobliug. I think this ins't possible. My solution was build .AAR package to put it into the flutter plugin.